# iOS MKLocalSearchRequest Exclude businesses

Tags: ios, search

I am using the MKLocalSearchRequest  class to allow the user to search for an address in my app.

I dont want the response results to contain businesses. Is there any way I can tell the class/API not to return businesses in the response?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can specify it in the `naturalLanguageQuery` portion of the `MKLocalSearchRequest` then it doesn't appear that the `MKMapItem` actually stores whether it's a business. The Apple documentation does say the `phoneNumber` should be used for a business but whether that's a guaranteed for all locations is an unknown.